# Error in the Perl Module

Tags: vmware, perl-module

While performing the action is the vmware, i am getting the below error.

ERROR
Can't load class 'HostSriovInfo' at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/VMware/VIMRuntime.pm line 52.

vSphere SDK for Perl version: 5.1.0
Script 'vmware-cmd' version: 5.1.0

Anyone can suggest to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try downloading a newer version of the SDK, and a version of perl that's newer that 10 years old.